# How do I notify Workmanager task completed to Service?

Tags: android, android-service, android-workmanager

My Worker(for API call) starts from Service and I want to completion event send into Service class.
What should be best approach?

**Calling from service:**

```
PeriodicWorkRequest request = new PeriodicWorkRequest
                .Builder(Worker.class, Constants.REPEAT_INTERVAL, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .addTag(TAG)
                .setConstraints(new Constraints.Builder().setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED).build())
                .build();
        WorkManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).enqueue(request);
```

**Calling from WorkManager:**

```
override fun doWork(): Result {
    // API call
    return Result.success()
}
```

Comment: Are you using Coroutines for example?

Comment: No @MariuszBrona

Comment: Can you describe your connection between objects?

Comment: @MariuszBrona, Please see the updated question.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so what I would do is I would create common object for both Worker and Service class and utilize Observer pattern. This `WorkObserver` object would behave as a proxy between Service and Worker. Using Koin for example, it would look something like that:

```kotlin
class MyWorker: Worker(), KoinComponent {

    private val workObserver: WorkObserver by inject()

    override fun doWork(): Result {
        val result = api.call().execute()
        if(result.isSuccessful) {
            workObserver.notifySuccess()
            return Result.success()
        } else {
            workObserver.notifyError()
            return Result.failure()
        }
    }

}

class MyService: Service(), KoinComponent {

    private val workObserver: WorkObserver by inject()

    override fun onCreate() {
        workObserver.setOnResultListener { result ->
            if(result) {
                //do something
            } else {
                // do something else
            }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        workObserver.setOnResultListener(null)
    }
}

class WorkObserver {

    private var onResultListener: ((Result) -> Unit)? = null

    fun setOnResultListener(listener: ((Result) -> Unit)?) {
         this.onResultListener = listener
    }

    fun notifySuccess() {
        this.onResultListener?.invoke(true)
    }

    fun notifyError() {
        this.onResultListener?.invoke(false)
    }
}
```

Of course you can use other DI tools for that, you can have a list of listeners and remove particular ones, you can pass any other object through the listener in WorkObserver with the payload you need. I just created a simple boolean passing

For that simple case however if you don't want to use DI, simple Object would do the work. However when your codebase grows and you are dealing with multithreading issues, or even accessing this object in other parts of the application it may lead to problems. I am using it only to pass information between objects, I don't recommend using it for storing data etc:

```kotlin
class MyWorker: Worker() {

    override fun doWork(): Result {
        val result = api.call().execute()
        if(result.isSuccessful) {
            WorkObserver.notifySuccess()
            return Result.success()
        } else {
            WorkObserver.notifyError()
            return Result.failure()
        }
    }

}

class MyService: Service() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        WorkObserver.setOnResultListener { result ->
            if(result) {
                //do something
            } else {
                // do something else
            }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        WorkObserver.setOnResultListener(null)
    }
}

object WorkObserver {

    private var onResultListener: ((Result) -> Unit)? = null

    fun setOnResultListener(listener: ((Result) -> Unit)?) {
         this.onResultListener = listener
    }

    fun notifySuccess() {
        this.onResultListener?.invoke(true)
    }

    fun notifyError() {
        this.onResultListener?.invoke(false)
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any other solution without DI?

Comment: Hey, check it now